# How to configure Intellij for the erlang build tool rebar3?

Tags: erlang, intellij-plugin, rebar3

I have started developing for Erlang using Rebar3 in the IntelliJ IDE and have run into the following problem - when trying to use the ide to clean or run i get the following error:

> Testing started at 8:33 AM ...
>   D:\DevelopmentTools\erl10.0.1\bin\escript.exe D:\DevelopmentTools\erl10.0.1\rebar\rebar3.cmd skip_deps=true clean -C C:\Users\coreRNM\AppData\Local\Temp\eunit_teamcity1\rebar.config
>   D:\DevelopmentTools\erl10.0.1\rebar\rebar3.cmd:2: syntax error before: set
>   escript: There were compilation errors.

It should be a fairly easy configuration but the code breaks in the following location.

> @echo off
>   setlocal
>   set rebarscript=%~f0
>   escript.exe "%rebarscript:.cmd=%" %*

My question is: has anyone experienced this before or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I have no idea what's happened here and it doesn't look like an integration issue. Better ask guys about running rebar3 on Windows.

Comment: When i run rebar3 from the terminal inside IntelliJ the commands all run, when i run any of the commands as part of the profiler - i get this problem, following the example at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-erlang.html. i can compile a plain erlang program, but not a rebar3 created program.